# How to output private properties of Powershell class

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, class

I'm developing a set of C# classes in order to be used with Powershell.

The properties of the classes are private in order not to be available to end users.

The issue I'm facing is that when trying to display the object (e.g. $myVar), the output is null since the properties are private.

Is there a way to use a function to return the properties I need?

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: You can use reflection to get the private properties

Comment: If the properties are private they cannot be accessed from outside the class. This is a pillar of OO programming. You have to understand which data have to accessed and in which way (read/write). Then you can design the class in the rigth way. I think is is more a design issue then a .NET specific question

Comment: I'm not sure whether reflection could be a solution to this.

It seems to be more of a matter on how Powershell outputs the objects.

Comment: I totally agree @MarcoBeninca, I have however the following question.

If I create a string variable in Powershell using the below code:
    `[string]$testString = "test"`

the only property that is available is the length of the string, yet when I print the variable using `$testString` I get its value.

Comment: "The properties of the classes are private in order not to be available to end users.” - sounds like you've succeeded :)

Comment: A class without public properties renders as its `.FullName` property (via the default `.ToString()` implementation). Try `Add-Type 'namespace Foo { public class Bar { private string Baz {get;set;} }}'; [Foo.Bar]::new()`. You could override `.ToString()` if you want something different.

Comment: If they aren't available to end users, why should they be available in powershell?

Comment: @WalterMitty Consider the implementation of a data structure like a stack. I want users to add/remove items through the methods (thus the properties of the class are private), but I would also like to output the items when sending the variable to the pipeline.

Comment: @mklement0 I'm already writing the classes in C#

I've tried using an auto property but since I was exposing a List<T> changes to the list were possible. Using an auto property with a getter that returns a read-only list seems to be the solution:

`    private List<PSObject> items;
    public IList<PSObject> Items
    {
        get { return items.AsReadOnly(); }
    }`